# How to locate element based on text()/contains criteria in Cypress.io

Tags: css-selectors, cypress

I need to locate an element/ verify presense of an element, based on the Text inside element, using something like:

```
//div[contains(text(),'<My intended text>')]
```

As Cypress.io do not support the XPATh yet, then how to locate it using alternate locators.
There seems to be lot of discussions around cssselectors :contains & when tried `div:contains('<My intended text>')` it failed to locate the element.
Given the fact that both XPATH & CSSLocators have good performance on modern browsers.

Kindly advise. Thanks

Comment: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/contains.html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so you are looking for the parent which holds 'My intended text'?

You can do so by using:

```js
cy.contains('My intended text')
```

and that's how you selected the element. Now you can use for example `.click()` to click on the element which holds 'My intended text'